# Uniqueness of non-linear weak forulation using Lax Milgram

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ a bounded domain. Let that we have a continuous and coercive on $H^1(\Omega)$ bilinear form $a(v,w)\,:\,H^1(\Omega)\times H^1(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}.$ Define the following weak formulation. Find $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that

\begin{equation}
a(u,v) = (f(u),v),\;\;\forall\,v\in H^1(\Omega)
\end{equation}

How can we ensure that there exists a unique weak solution of the above problem? It is sufficient to holds the Lax-Milgram Lemma and $f$ is Lipchitz continuous? If the answer is yes, can anyone give me a reference?

Comment: There is a wide range of different possibilities available. Do you have more assumptions on $f$?

Comment: It is not sufficient that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous, try, e.g., $f(u) = a(u,\cdot) - g$ for some $g \in H^1(\Omega)^*\setminus\{0\}$. You neet that $f$ has a small Lipschitz constant.